# Hide internal faces of a mesh with instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to hide internal faces/vertices of a cube instance that is placed along the plane? I've thought on something like hide faces that are in same position or too close but couldn't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Hide or remove? And why not use a Cube primitive node instead?

Comment: Hide. Whats the diference using Cube primitive?

Comment: Hiding usually means still having the geometry but not displaying it for whatever reason. Your question is missing an explanation why you need that, do you want to only remove internal faces, or also realize the cubes? Maybe also merge them. Why are you instancing an existing cube object rather than using *Cube* node? Maybe you're planning to replace the cube with something different later? This most probably would render any solution for the cube alone ineffective...

Answer (score 2):

To combine multiple meshes without keeping the intersecting geometry, use the `Mesh Boolean` in `Union` mode:

[image: joined cubes]

Comment: Mesh boolean crash blender on larger planes.

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem with Jummit's answer is that it can crash Blender (perhaps too many booleans is just too heavy on CPU), then it seems you're fine with merging the vertices and you simply want to end up with a single cuboid with subdivisions analogous to the plane subdivisions. Something like this could work then:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to add this nodes to the cube or plane?

Comment: is it possible to combine these nodes with the ones I already have?

Comment: @ThiagoM. see my last comment under your question: it's unclear what you need. For example, when you ask "is it possible to combine these nodes with the ones I already have?" - the answer is of course **yes** - just put them side by side and use *Join Geometry* node to connect them. It's most probably not what you actually want, but I'm honestly unable to guess what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: What is not clear in my question? I got a plane, i got a cube, i place instance of this cube on every vertex of the plane. I need to hide/not render the faces/vertices of those instances that are in the same position, or inner faces. Mesh boolean gives me the expected result but it doesn't work with a high vertices count.

Can you show me how the nodes you suggested would work combined with the ones i already got?

Comment: @ThiagoM. One thing that is not clear is what do you mean by "hide" - normally we call it "deleting". If you hide something, you expect it to still affect some stuff, e.g. physics. Another thing that is not clear, is why you would want to merge the old node setup with a new one, if the new node setup does everything the old setup does. An analogy to that would be buying a new car and asking the seller if it can be merged with the old one. Perhaps the analogy is wrong, but that's how I understand your question.